# boost test and async IO : memory access violation at address : no mapping at fault address

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, boost-test

i am trying to setup a boost test for async I/O for tcpip.

my function to send tcp msg:

```
    int TcpClient::sendMsgToServer(string msg) {
    if (isConnected == true) {
        Logger::debug("Asynch send request for msg: " + msg, __LINE__,
                __FILE__);
        sendSequence++;
        msg.append("\r\n");
        int length = msg.length() + 2; //+2 is for \r\n
        char* buffer = (char*) msg.c_str();
        Logger::debug(buffer, __LINE__, __FILE__);
        m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, length),
                boost::bind(&fingigcc::TcpClient::sendMsgToServerErrorHandler,
                        this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        std::string sentMsg = "Sent Msg: " + msg;
        Logger::debug(sentMsg, __LINE__, __FILE__);


        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}

    void TcpClient::sendMsgToServerErrorHandler(
            const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        Logger::debug("Sending complete: ", __LINE__, __FILE__);
        sendResponseSequence++;
        int i = error.value();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss.clear();
        ss << i;
        Logger::debug("RESULTCODE: " + ss.str(), __LINE__, __FILE__);
        if (i == 0) {
            Logger::debug("RESULT: " + error.message(), __LINE__, __FILE__);

        } else {
            Logger::crit(error.message(), __LINE__, __FILE__);
            m_Socket.close();
            isConnected = false;
            connectionStateChanged(isConnected);
        }

    }
```

now this function works fine if i just run it in the main thread ( not running doing a boost test)

my boost test function looks like this:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( CommunicationCore_sendTcpIpMsg_test ) {

    CommunicationCoreFixture f;
    int compare = f.c->initializeTcpIpConnection(serverAddress, serverPort); // i initialize the connection here. runs fine with any issue
    sleep(2);
    compare = f.c->sendMsgToServer("IDENTIFY console-2");
    BOOST_MESSAGE("Sending returned value : " << compare);
    BOOST_CHECK(compare == 0);
}
```

and it fails with the following error:

```
    Entering test case "CommunicationCore_sendTcpIpMsg_test"
unknown location(0): fatal error in "CommunicationCore_sendTcpIpMsg_test": memory access violation at address: 0x01003255: no mapping at fault address
*****************Test is aborted
```

Is there anything i should be aware of while testing such async functions?

my build information is:

```
Platform: linux
Compiler: GNU C++ version 4.7.2
STL     : GNU libstdc++ version 20120920
Boost   : 1.49.0
```

---

EDIT:

I have tried modifying it in the following manner as well..but still getting the same error:

```
int TcpClient::sendMsgToServer(string msg) {
    if (isConnected == true) {
        Logger::debug("Asynch send request for msg: " + msg, __LINE__,
                __FILE__);
        sendSequence++;
        msg.append("\r\n");
    char *buffer = new char[msg.size() + 1];
    buffer[msg.size()] = 0;
    memcpy(buffer, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
    Logger::debug(buffer, __LINE__, __FILE__);

    m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, (msg.size() + 1)),
            boost::bind(&fingigcc::TcpClient::sendMsgToServerErrorHandler,
                    this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        std::string sentMsg = "Sent Msg: " + msg;
        Logger::debug(sentMsg, __LINE__, __FILE__);


        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the default constructor of `CommunicationCoreFixture` make sure its `c` member points at a valid object?

Comment: yes. infact i should mention that if i remove the part:

 m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, length),
                boost::bind(&fingigcc::TcpClient::sendMsgToServerErrorHandler,
                        this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));  it runs without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, length)` -- but `msg` object is local, and its `c_str()` result gets invalid after `msg` goes out of scope! So you actually pass a *temporary buffer* to an asynchronous operation. The buffer doesn't outlive this operation, so segfault is inevitable.

Comment: edited it upon your suggestion..not sure i did it correct. but still getting the same error

Comment: @Shrouk Hasan Khan it looks correct now. If you still get a crash, perhaps it comes from another (but similar) place. Besides, check that `TcpClient` instance outlives the async operations.

Comment: infact you are correct. the error comes from initializing the boost::thread in a function ( not mentioned here ) which does not live long enough to be passed along to sendMsgToServer .